# Sort/stable_sort custom compare function cause some strange issues

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator

I have very basic experience of custom function for sort/stable_sort API.
Below is the source code I am running under Windows Visual Studio 2017.
Please help analyze what is the problem, do I miss anything or what is the theory behind? Thanks for the help

```
// 10_3_1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
#define MAX_INPUT_NO    (10u)

typedef bool(* sort_func_t)(const int input_a, const int input_b);

bool is_shorter(const int input_a, const int input_b)
{
#if 0
    //this portion will show the iteration overlap
    if (input_a > input_b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
#else
    //both below works
    //return input_a < input_b;
    return input_a > input_b;

#endif
}

void elimDups(vector<int> &dat, sort_func_t func)
{
    vector<int>::iterator temp = dat.begin();
    std::stable_sort(dat.begin(), dat.end(), func);
    //sort(dat.begin(), dat.end());

    temp = unique(dat.begin(), dat.end());
    dat.erase(temp, dat.end());
}

void print_vec(vector<int> &dat)
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator index = dat.cbegin();
    int i = 0;
    for (; index < dat.cend(); index++)
    {
        cout << "dat[" << i << "] = " << dat.at(i++) << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    int ia[MAX_INPUT_NO] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5};
    a.assign(ia, ia + MAX_INPUT_NO);
    print_vec(a);
    elimDups(a, is_shorter);
    print_vec(a);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem I face when I play with if-else portion, it gives me the invalid comparator assert error.

> 1. If I define the custom function like below use the if-else pattern, it works fine.

```
bool is_shorter(const int input_a, const int input_b)
{
#if 1
    //this portion will show the iteration overlap
    if (input_a > input_b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
#else
    //below works
    return input_a > input_b;
#endif
}
```

Below is the result I get.

expect result from item 1

[image]

> 2. If I define the custom comparator function like below, it also uses the if-else pattern, it will fail with "Invalid comparator" Error.

```
bool is_shorter(const int input_a, const int input_b)
{
#if 1
    //this portion will show the iteration overlap
    if (input_a > input_b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
#else
    //below works
    return input_a > input_b;
#endif
}
```

Below is the error message I get:

error message from visual studio 2017

[image]

> 3. But if I just use return, then it works fine for both direction.

```
bool is_shorter(const int input_a, const int input_b)
{
#if 0
    //this portion will show the iteration overlap
    if (input_a > input_b)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
#else
    //both below works
    //return input_a < input_b;
    return input_a > input_b;

#endif
}
```

Comment: The custom comparator must have a strict weak ordering. The relations, `<` and `>`, both have a strict weak ordering but `<=` and `>=` do not. It's failing because the comparator is returning `true` when `input_a <= input_b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
if (input_a > input_b)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

is convoluted way to say:

```
return !(input_a > input_b);
```

and negation of `greater then` is `less or equal`:

```
return input_a <= input_b; // logically same as before
```

The problem is you cannot use `less or equal` relation for sorting as it does not provide strict weak ordering the algorithm requires. You can use less though:

```
return input_a < input_b;
```

or greater then as you used in your code when it works.

Comment: Some (or all?) versions of Visual Studio will catch a <= compare function if a debug build is done.

Comment: @Slava, Thanks for the explanation.