# C++ program crashes when trying to sort a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector, sigabrt

I'm trying to sort an array of strings in C++, but I am getting the following error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'  
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

The following program causes the previous error. I got the error when `v` has 17 elements, but everything works fine when `v` has less elements.

Could someone point me out what is the problem? I'm using *gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)*

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool comp (string s1, string s2) {
    if (s1.size() < s2.size())
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main () {   
    vector<string> v = { "a", "a", "a", "a",
                         "a", "a", "a", "a",
                         "a", "a", "a", "a",
                         "a", "a", "a", "a",
                         "a" };
    
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The comparator for `std::sort` requires _strict weak ordering_. Think of it as "less than". In your setup, `"a" < "a"` is _true_ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: What @MikeVine said, so try `return s1.size() < s2.size();`. Sidenote: Your comparator is a bit expensive. Make it `bool comp (const string& s1, const string& s2)` to not copy the strings every time.

Comment: Generally, if you have `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` that can be replaced directly by `retur condition;`.

Comment: The behavior of the exception being thrown is intriguing. This only occurs if comparing greater-than-or-equal semantics with by-value arguments. Passing by reference, or comparing with less-than doesn't produce this ([compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1KhT87))

Comment: @Human-Compiler Undefined behavior at play :-)

Comment: Do you want the longest strings first, is that it? In that case `return s2.size() < s1.size();`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would say `return s1.size() > s2.size()` is probably clearer, as you don't have the chance to miss the swapped argument order. In fact, you might as well use `std::greater<>()`.

Comment: @Justin Perhaps - but I usually go with `operator<` to not have to think about whether the type I'm sorting has implemented `operator>` or not. `operator<` is required for `std::sort`, `operator>` is not so if the underlaying type has a lazy implementation, `operator<` will work. Not that it matters for `size_t` - but still. :-)

Comment: I was coding a comparison function based on two criteria and I was getting the error I mentioned above. I have shortened the code to come up with a minimal example. I was unaware I could get a runtime error in case of a wrong `comp` function. I have noticed that returning the size difference directly everything worked fine, but I was not understanding why. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like a dupe to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833614/sort-stable-sort-custom-compare-function-cause-some-strange-issues/59833700#59833700

Comment: @SérgioQMedeiros If you want to compare two or more things, the easiest is to make a tuple and compare the tuple. `std::tie(lhs.ref_a(), lhs.ref_b()) < std::tie(rhs.ref_a(), rhs.ref_b())`. `std::tuple` implements the comparison correctly. If you have some that are values, you can use `std::forward_as_tuple(lhs.size(), lhs.ref_b()) < std::forward_as_tuple(rhs.size(), rhs.ref_b())`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks anyway, probably wanted to point that writing unreadable `if( ) return false; else return true;` is not just longer way to express obvious but leads to hidden bugs. In this case `return !s1.size() < s2.size();` would make mistake more obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comparator you pass to sort must satisfy the [named requirement Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare):

> Establishes strict weak ordering relation with the following
> properties
>
> ```
> For all a, comp(a,a)==false
> If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false
> if comp(a,b)==true and comp(b,c)==true then comp(a,c)==true
> ```

With your comparator: `comp(a,a) == true`. As you do not fullfill the preconditions of `std::sort` your code has undefined behavior.