# C++ std::sort custom comparator runs indefinitely when the comparator returns true

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, strict-weak-ordering

So I encountered this very weird behavior on an edge case when sorting a vector using a custom comparator.

When running this code, it will not halt, and goes forever:

```
int main() {
    auto comp = [](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return true;
    };
    
    vector<int> vec{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);
    
    for (int num : vec)
        cout << num;
    
    return 0;
}
```

however, when I change the `true` to `false`, it works perfectly.

```
auto comp = [](int lhs, int rhs) {
    return false;
};
```

What's weirder, when I decrease the number of `0`'s to be sorted, it also works perfectly. (It works with 16 or less `0`'s, when I add one more `0` to make it 17, the program will not halt again. (Will g++ switch to another sorting algorithm if the length exceeds 16?)

```
vector<int> vec{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Why is this the case? Am I missing some important concepts in C++'s `sort()` function?

Comment: your comparator does not implement a strict weak ordering -> undefined behavior

Comment: almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014782/c-program-crashes-when-trying-to-sort-a-vector-of-strings/64014891#64014891

Comment: *"Will g++ switch to another sorting algorithm if the length exceeds 16?"* It is legal, and indeed, compiler tends to use a mix of algorithms for performance, guaranteed complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comparator:

```
auto comp = [](int lhs, int rhs) {
   return true;
};
```

violates the requirement of `std::sort` that the comparator must establish a *strict-weak-ordering*. Note that this function returns `true` regardless of the order of arguments, implying that 2 elements can both be less than the other, which doesn't really make sense. Violating this requirement of `std::sort` invokes undefined behavior (this is sufficient to explain the differing behavior you see with different `vector` sizes).

---

On the other hand, this comparator:

```
auto comp = [](int lhs, int rhs) {
    return false;
};
```

is perfectly fine. It basically says that no elements compare less than any other (i.e. they are all equivalent). This satisfies *strict-weak-ordering*, so `std::sort` will work just fine with it.

Of course, `std::sort` won't do anything useful with the second comparator, since all the elements are already "sorted". This might reorder the elements though; but if you use `std::stable_sort` then the original range is guaranteed to be unchanged.

Comment: you already had my vote. I wasnt sure whether to close as dupe, but this answer really adds something