# Process returned (0xc0000005) for rare cases while sorting a vector using sort()

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I ran the code for random vectors filled with 1 and 2-digit numbers. And there's no error till the size of the array becomes **greater than 16**. For arrays from size 17 there are few cases where the code fails and returns 'Process returned [some no.] 0xc0000005 '.

So my code basically outputs the largest number formed by shuffling given numbers(can be a 2 or more digit number as well). Eg. Input: 23 39 92 6. Output: 9263923. And for that I've used a sort function to arrange the given numbers in the required order. I defined the comparator function for it in the following manner:

```
bool sortcomp(int a,int b){

    /*cout<<"comparing:"<<a<<" & "<<b;
    cout<<endl;*/

    int a1=a;           //a1 is the First digit in a
    int b1=b;           //b1 is the First digit in b
    int dig1=1;         //Number of digits in a
    int dig2=1;         //Number of digits in b
    
    while(a1/10>0){     
        a1=a1/10;
        dig1++;
    }
    while(b1/10>0){
        b1=b1/10;
        dig2++;
    }
    
    if(a1>b1){
        return true;
    }
    if(b1>a1){
        return false;
    }
    if(a/10==0&&b/10==0){
        return true;
    }
    
    if(a/10>0){
        int x=1;
        while(dig1>1){
            x*=10;
            dig1--;
        }
        a-=a1*x;
    }
    if(b/10>0){
        int x=1;
        while(dig2>1){
            x*=10;
            dig2--;
        }
        b-=b1*x;
    }
    return sortcomp(a,b);
}
```

called using: `sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),sortcomp);`

Also I used `cout<<"comparing:"<<a<<" & "<<b;` in the comparator to check what's happening. And what I saw is it starts comparing garbage values for the cases where it fails.

Examples of the failed cases:

n=17: 40 99 97 7 54 4 37 85 99 92 13 12 82 83 51 29 37

n=18: 64 9 71 67 56 93 80 89 13 9 23 1 43 70 57 55 37 91

n=20: 84 98 85 88 97 22 3 43 15 55 98 18 34 29 53 18 85 18 98 16

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Your comparator doesn't satisfy strict-weak-ordering. Elements 4 and 6 return true when compared in either order.`if(a/10==0&&b/10==0){ return true;}`

Comment: does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014782/c-program-crashes-when-trying-to-sort-a-vector-of-strings/64014891#64014891 its a slightly different case, but answer applies here as well

Comment: @idclev463035818 There are many questions of this nature, except that in each case the reason the constraint is violated differs. Maybe they're all dupes, but I'm not sure what the canonical dupe target is for this.

Comment: @cigien same thoughts here, i didnt mean to promote my answer, it was just the one that I could find quickest

Comment: @idclev463035818 No worries, it's a valid answer, nothing wrong with that I think :)

Comment: @cigien its a problem that comes up quite often, I also make this mistake on a regular basis. Unfortunately there is no fool-proof way to check for strict weak ordering (other than lots of testing)

Comment: `x/10 == 0` and `x/10>0` are more commonly written  `x < 10` and `x >= 10`.

Comment: @cigien maybe "How can I verify that my comp implements a strict weak ordering?" could make a good dupe target, but I don't know a good answer ;)

Comment: @cigien that piece of code returns true only when both the numbers are single digit and they're equal. (Bcoz I already checked for the cases where the first digits are unequal). Hence sortcomp(4,6) will return false.

Comment: @idclev463035818 That would be ideal, but a robust solution for that is impossible. Seems all these questions are not dupes, even though the answers are essentially the same :p

Comment: Ok, but even for equal elements, the comparison should return `false`.

Comment: @cigien Oh. Yes, it worked. Thanks for the reply. But I'm unaware of how it matters whether the function returns true or false for equal elements.?

Comment: See the link in the second comment.

Comment: @cigien Got it, Thanks!

Comment: just abandoning the question isnt nice so eventually I flagged as duplicate